# Generating tests with opensource framework like Limesurvey

Tags: open-source, limesurvey

I have a certain number of questions, from which I would like to generate a certain number of tests, but each test only has x of the total n questions (so not all the questions in one test). 
Basically I'm looking for a test preparation framework for multiple choice questions.

I discovered Limesurvey as an opensource framework which might be useful for this requirement. Could I do above tasks easily with Limesurvey (how?), or should I consider another solution (which one)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LimeSurvey, you can use different method. The best i use is :

- Put all the question in the same Randomization group name : [http://manual.limesurvey.org/QS:Random_group](http://manual.limesurvey.org/QS%3aRandom_group)
- Add a short text question (code is DONE) at start and hide it : [http://manual.limesurvey.org/QS:Hidden](http://manual.limesurvey.org/QS%3aHidden)
- At each question, put the relevance equation to DONE!="done"
- AT the Xth question, put an Equation question with {DONE="done"}

Then :

- All question in the Randomization group name are shuffled
- The question after the Eqation question aren't showned.

You have X question inside Yours questions.

You have another system here : [http://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Survey_behaviour#Version_2.0_And_Newer](http://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds%3a_Survey_behaviour#Version_2.0_And_Newer)

:)